# Fullcalendar not loading view plugins using Webpack Encore

Tags: javascript, jquery, symfony, webpack, fullcalendar

I'm using this template [AdminLte v3](https://github.com/ColorlibHQ/AdminLTE) and I'm trying to import all the JS plugins/libraries used in this [calendar.html](https://github.com/ColorlibHQ/AdminLTE/blob/master/pages/calendar.html) file on my Symfony project. I'm using Webpack Encore, so all my JS is on 1 file and linked to the template I use for the view.

The JS code to load the FullCalendar is this:

```js
 $(function () {

    /* initialize the external events
     -----------------------------------------------------------------*/
    function ini_events(ele) {
      ele.each(function () {

        // create an Event Object (http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/Event_Object/)
        // it doesn't need to have a start or end
        var eventObject = {
          title: $.trim($(this).text()) // use the element's text as the event title
        }

        // store the Event Object in the DOM element so we can get to it later
        $(this).data('eventObject', eventObject)

        // make the event draggable using jQuery UI
        $(this).draggable({
          zIndex        : 1070,
          revert        : true, // will cause the event to go back to its
          revertDuration: 0  //  original position after the drag
        })

      })
    }

    ini_events($('#external-events div.external-event'))

    /* initialize the calendar
     -----------------------------------------------------------------*/
    //Date for the calendar events (dummy data)
    var date = new Date()
    var d    = date.getDate(),
        m    = date.getMonth(),
        y    = date.getFullYear()

    var Calendar = FullCalendar.Calendar;
    var Draggable = FullCalendarInteraction.Draggable;

    var containerEl = document.getElementById('external-events');
    var checkbox = document.getElementById('drop-remove');
    var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');

    // initialize the external events
    // -----------------------------------------------------------------

    new Draggable(containerEl, {
      itemSelector: '.external-event',
      eventData: function(eventEl) {
        console.log(eventEl);
        return {
          title: eventEl.innerText,
          backgroundColor: window.getComputedStyle( eventEl ,null).getPropertyValue('background-color'),
          borderColor: window.getComputedStyle( eventEl ,null).getPropertyValue('background-color'),
          textColor: window.getComputedStyle( eventEl ,null).getPropertyValue('color'),
        };
      }
    });

    var calendar = new Calendar(calendarEl, {
      plugins: [ 'bootstrap', 'interaction', 'dayGrid', 'timeGrid' ],
      header    : {
        left  : 'prev,next today',
        center: 'title',
        right : 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay'
      },
      'themeSystem': 'bootstrap',
      //Random default events
      events    : [
        {
          title          : 'All Day Event',
          start          : new Date(y, m, 1),
          backgroundColor: '#f56954', //red
          borderColor    : '#f56954', //red
          allDay         : true
        },
        {
          title          : 'Long Event',
          start          : new Date(y, m, d - 5),
          end            : new Date(y, m, d - 2),
          backgroundColor: '#f39c12', //yellow
          borderColor    : '#f39c12' //yellow
        },
        {
          title          : 'Meeting',
          start          : new Date(y, m, d, 10, 30),
          allDay         : false,
          backgroundColor: '#0073b7', //Blue
          borderColor    : '#0073b7' //Blue
        },
        {
          title          : 'Lunch',
          start          : new Date(y, m, d, 12, 0),
          end            : new Date(y, m, d, 14, 0),
          allDay         : false,
          backgroundColor: '#00c0ef', //Info (aqua)
          borderColor    : '#00c0ef' //Info (aqua)
        },
        {
          title          : 'Birthday Party',
          start          : new Date(y, m, d + 1, 19, 0),
          end            : new Date(y, m, d + 1, 22, 30),
          allDay         : false,
          backgroundColor: '#00a65a', //Success (green)
          borderColor    : '#00a65a' //Success (green)
        },
        {
          title          : 'Click for Google',
          start          : new Date(y, m, 28),
          end            : new Date(y, m, 29),
          url            : 'http://google.com/',
          backgroundColor: '#3c8dbc', //Primary (light-blue)
          borderColor    : '#3c8dbc' //Primary (light-blue)
        }
      ],
      editable  : true,
      droppable : true, // this allows things to be dropped onto the calendar !!!
      drop      : function(info) {
        // is the "remove after drop" checkbox checked?
        if (checkbox.checked) {
          // if so, remove the element from the "Draggable Events" list
          info.draggedEl.parentNode.removeChild(info.draggedEl);
        }
      }    
    });

    calendar.render();
    // $('#calendar').fullCalendar()

    /* ADDING EVENTS */
    var currColor = '#3c8dbc' //Red by default
    //Color chooser button
    var colorChooser = $('#color-chooser-btn')
    $('#color-chooser > li > a').click(function (e) {
      e.preventDefault()
      //Save color
      currColor = $(this).css('color')
      //Add color effect to button
      $('#add-new-event').css({
        'background-color': currColor,
        'border-color'    : currColor
      })
    })
    $('#add-new-event').click(function (e) {
      e.preventDefault()
      //Get value and make sure it is not null
      var val = $('#new-event').val()
      if (val.length == 0) {
        return
      }

      //Create events
      var event = $('<div />')
      event.css({
        'background-color': currColor,
        'border-color'    : currColor,
        'color'           : '#fff'
      }).addClass('external-event')
      event.html(val)
      $('#external-events').prepend(event)

      //Add draggable funtionality
      ini_events(event)

      //Remove event from text input
      $('#new-event').val('')
    })
  })
```

As you can see, it needs Jquery and multiple objects and methods that belong to the plugin, so I imported them like this:

```js
var $ = require('jquery');
import * as FullCalendar from 'admin-lte/plugins/fullcalendar/main.js';
import * as bootstrap from 'admin-lte/plugins/fullcalendar-bootstrap/main.js';
import * as interaction from 'admin-lte/plugins/fullcalendar-interaction/main.js';
import * as dayGrid from 'admin-lte/plugins/fullcalendar-daygrid/main.js';
import * as timeGrid from 'admin-lte/plugins/fullcalendar-timegrid/main.js';
```

But I get this error:

[image: img]

I also tried like this and it still doesn't work:

```js
var $ = require('jquery');
var FullCalendar = require('admin-lte/plugins/fullcalendar/main');
var bootstrap = require('admin-lte/plugins/fullcalendar-bootstrap/main');
var interaction = require('admin-lte/plugins/fullcalendar-interaction/main');
var dayGrid = require('admin-lte/plugins/fullcalendar-daygrid/main');
var timeGrid = require('admin-lte/plugins/fullcalendar-timegrid/main');
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: The routes are correct 100%, and I also tried using import 'route/to/plugin'; but it still doesn't work. Maybe I'm importing incorrectly? But the FullCalendar object still gets imported.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the answer. My approach was bad and I shouldn't have copied that code as it is.

There's an example doing what I want in the [official documentation](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/initialize-es6) and [their official repo on github](https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar-example-projects/tree/master/webpack).

Here's a sample:

```js
import { Calendar } from '@fullcalendar/core';
import dayGridPlugin from '@fullcalendar/daygrid';

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');

  var calendar = new Calendar(calendarEl, {
    plugins: [ dayGridPlugin ]
  });

  calendar.render();
});
```